# Countdown timer not work in my HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a countdown timer to work on my web page, but its not working, and I can't figure out why. I don't know if its because I linked it wrong in my HTML or if its because I missed something in my code. Any help would be appreciate.

```js
"use strict";



setInterval(function() { ... }, 1000); // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second

// Function to display current date / time on the site
setInterval(function displayTimeAndDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var hours = today.getHours();
  var minutes = today.getMinutes();
  var seconds = today.getSeconds();

  var date = today.getDate();
  var month = today.getMonth();
  var year = today.getFullYear();

  var amOrPm;

  // Check if it's a.m or p.m
  if (hours < 12) {
    amOrPm = "a.m";
  } else {
    amOrPm = "p.m";
  }

  document.getElementById('date').innerText = date + ":" + month + ":" + year;
  document.getElementById('time').innerText = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + amOrPm;
}, 1000);

setInterval(function countdown() {
  // Set the desired date (American date format: Month/Day/Year) to countdown to and the current date
  var endDate = new Date('07/04/2018 09:00 PM');
  var currentDate = new Date();

  // Get the "distance" between the dates
  var distance = endDate - currentDate;

  // Initialize days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var oneSecond = 1000; // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
  var oneMinute = oneSecond * 60;
  var oneHour = oneMinute * 60;
  var oneDay = oneHour * 24;

  // Get distance in days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / oneDay);
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % oneDay) / oneHour);
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % oneHour) / oneMinute);
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % oneMinute) / oneSecond);

  // Place 0 before the numbers if the are lower than 10
  hours = (hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;


  document.getElementById('dLeft').innerText = days;
  document.getElmentById('hLeft').innerText = hours;
  document.getElementById('mLeft').innerText = minutes;
  document.getElementById('sLeft').innerText = seconds;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <!--
         New Perspectives on HTML5 and CSS3, 7th Edition
         Tutorial 9
         Review Assignment
   
         Tulsa's Summer Party
         Author: 
         Date:   
   
         Filename: tny_july.html
   
      -->
      
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <title>Tulsa's Summer Party</title>
      <link href="tny_base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <link href="tny_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="tny_timer.js" defer></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <header>
         <nav class="horizontal">       
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Night Beat</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Tulsa Times</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">City Links</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>  
              
         <img src="tny_banner2.png" id="logoImg" alt="" />
         <h1>Tulsa's<br />Summer Party</h1>
         <h2 id="timeHeading">Welcome to Tulsa</h2>
         <div id="currentTime"><span>11/3/2017</span><span>2:45:12 p.m.</span></div>
      </header>

      <article>
         <section>
            <h1>Countdown to the Fireworks</h1>
            <div id="countdown">
               <div><span id="dLeft">58</span><br />Days</div>
               <div><span id="hLeft">10</span><br />Hrs</div>
               <div><span id="mLeft">14</span><br />Mins</div>
               <div><span id="sLeft">48</span><br />Secs</div>
            </div>         
            <p>Celebrate the nation's birthday at <em>Tulsa's Summer
               Party</em>, a daylong extravaganza in downtown
               Tulsa on the 4th of July. The festivities start at 9 a.m.
               with a 5K and 10K walk or race. A great event
               for the whole family. Sign up as an individual or
               part of a team.
            </p>
            <p>The <em>Farmer's
               Market</em> is also back with farm-fresh produce,
               meats, and dairy. There's something for every
               pallet.</p>
         </section>

         <section>
            <p>Live music starts at 11 a.m. and continues through the day 
               with special appearances from <em>Falstaff
               Ergo</em>, <em>Crop Circles</em>, <em>Prairie Wind</em> and 
               <em>James Po</em>.
            </p>         
            <p>At 9 p.m. enjoy the <em>fireworks</em> that have won awards
               as the best in the Midwest, designed and presented by
               <em>Wizard Works</em>. Arrive early for the best seats!
            </p>
            <p>After the show, dance the night away to the music of 
               the <em>Chromotones</em>. 
            </p>
            <p>See you on the 4th!</p>
         </section>
         
         <nav class="vertical">
            <h1>Party Links</h1>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">5K and 10K Run</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Famer's Market</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Wizard Works</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Falstaff Ergo</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Crop Circles</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">James Po</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Tulsa Fireworks</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Prairie Wind</a></li>
            </ul>
         </nav>         
      </article>
      
      <footer>
         <address>
            Tulsa Summer Party &#183; 
            340 Main Street, Tulsa, OK 74102 &#183;
            (918) 555-3481
         </address>
      </footer>
   </body>

</html>
```

Screenshot of my page: http://prntscr.com/isp2hu

Ive been googling and looking at possible issues and nothing has solved my problem so far.

EDIT: Added my CSS

```html
@charset "utf-8";

@font-face {
   font-family: Segment14;
   src: url('segment14.woff') format('woff'),
        url('segment14.ttf') format('truetype');
}

/*
   New Perspectives on HTML5 and CSS3, 7th Edition
   Tutorial 9
   Review Assignment

   Tulsa's Summer Party Layout Style Sheet
  
   Filename: tny_layout.css

   Segment14 font designed by Paul Flo Williams. Download at:
   http://www.1001fonts.com/segment14-font.html#styles

*/


/* HTML and Body styles */

html {
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(120, 84, 23), rgb(51, 51, 51));
   font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
   min-height: 100%;
}

body { 
   margin: 0px auto;
   min-width: 340px;
   max-width: 1020px;  
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
}


/* Header styles */

header img#logoImg {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
}

header {
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 70%, rgb(185, 0, 102));
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
   color: white;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
}

header > h1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 15px;
   right: 10px;
   text-align: right;  
   font-size: 1.3em;
   letter-spacing: 0.05em;
   line-height: 1em;
   font-family: 'Times New Roman', serif;
   font-weight: normal;
   color: rgba(255, 0, 192, 0.7);
}

header > h2 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 15px;
   left: 10px;
   font-size: 0.9em;
   font-weight: normal;
   color: rgba(255, 82, 192, 0.8);
}

/* Navigation list styles */

header nav.horizontal {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   -webkit-flex: 0 1;
   flex: 0 1;   
}

body header nav ul {
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
   flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

nav.horizontal ul li {
   -webkit-flex: 1 1;
   flex: 1 1;
   font-size: 0.8em;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   height: 1.5em; 
   font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
   text-shadow: black 2px 1px 0px, black 4px 2px 5px;     
}

nav.horizontal ul li a {
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
   display: block;
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
   text-align: center;
}

nav.horizontal ul li a:hover {
   background-color: rgba(255, 88, 192, 0.5);
}

/* Time Clock Styles */

div#currentTime {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 35px;
   left: 10px;   
   background-color: transparent;
   border: hidden;
   color: rgba(255, 82, 192, 0.8);
   width: 140px;
   font-size: 0.6em;
   line-height: 1.1em;
   font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-weight: normal;
}

div#currentTime span {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
}

/* Styles for the Countdown Clock */

div#countdown {
   width: 100%;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
   flex-flow: row nowrap;
   margin-top: 10px;

}

div#countdown div {
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   line-height: 1.5em;
   font-size: 0.5em;
   font-family: segment14, sans-serif;
   color: white;
   background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.7);
   margin: 0px 1px;
   padding: 5px;
   color: white;
}

div#countdown div span {
   font-size: 2em;   
}

/* Article Styles */

article { 
   background: white;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
   flex-flow: row wrap; 
}

article section, article nav.vertical {
   -webkit-flex: 1 1 300px;
   flex: 1 1 300px;
}

section h1 {
   font-size: 1.2em;
   text-align: center;
   margin: 10px;
}

section p {
   margin: 20px;
}

/*Section 1 styles */

article section:nth-of-type(1) {
   background-color: rgba(255, 0, 192, 0.6);
}

/* Section 2 styles */

article section:nth-of-type(2) {
   background-color: rgba(255, 0, 192, 0.5);
}


/* Vertical navigation list styles */

nav.vertical {
   background-color: rgba(255, 0, 192, 0.7);
}

nav.vertical h1 {
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
   text-shadow: rgba(192, 0, 145, 0.8) 2px 2px 5px;
   font-size: 1.35em;
   letter-spacing: 3px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
   background-color: rgba(233, 0, 177, 0.5);
}


nav.vertical ul li {
   font-size: 0.82em;
   letter-spacing: 3px;
   text-align: center;
}


nav.vertical ul li a {
   display: block;
   padding-left: 30px;
   height: 32px;
   line-height: 32px;
   width: auto;
   color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

nav.vertical ul li a:hover {
   background-color: rgba(255, 192, 0, 0.45);
}


/* Page footer styles */

footer {
   clear: left;
   display: block;
}

footer address {
   display: block;
   font-style: normal;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 0.5em;
   line-height: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: rgb(215, 0, 152);
   color: white;
}

/* =============================================
   Tablet and Desktop Styles: greater than 510px
   =============================================
*/
@media only screen and (min-width:511px) {
   
   header > h1 {
      font-size: 1.9em;
   }
   
   header > h2 {
      font-size: 1.1em;
   }
   
   div#currentTime {
      font-size: 0.9em;
      line-height: 1em;
   } 
   
   div#countdown {
      font-size: 1.3em;
   }
   
   footer address {
      font-size: 0.6em;
   }     
}

/* =============================================
   Tablet and Desktop Styles: greater than 640px
   =============================================
*/
@media only screen and (min-width:641px) {
      
   header > h1 {
      font-size: 2.4em;
   }
   
   header > h2 {
      font-size: 1.3em;
   }  
      
   nav.horizontal ul li {
      font-size: 1em;
   }
   
   div#currentTime {
      font-size: 1em;
      line-height: 1.1em;
      top: 40px;
   }   
   
   div#countdown  {
      font-size: 1.5em;
   }    
   
   footer address {
      font-size: 0.8em;
   }   
}

/* =============================================
   Tablet and Desktop Styles: greater than 720px
   =============================================
*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 721px) {
   header > h1 {
      font-size: 3.3em;
   }

   header > h2 {
      font-size: 1.5em;
   }
   
   div#currentTime {
      font-size: 1.1em;
      line-height: 1.2em;
      top: 40px;
   }
   
   div#countdown {
      font-size: 1.7em;
   }      
}

/* =============================================
   Tablet and Desktop Styles: greater than 1020px
   =============================================
*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1021px) {

   body {
      margin: 40px auto;
   }   
}
```

Comment: Please don't post your code to 3rd party sites. It's inconvenient to have to go out and get the code from various places and those links can die over time, making your question unreadable. Just include your code in your question.

Comment: So where do you actually call your functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced your functions with my own functions.

To update the countdown / current time/date every seconds, I set an interval that executes the function every second:

```
setInterval(function() { ... }, 1000); // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
```

Your way of gettings the date's hours, minutes, etc. is

```js
// Function to display current date / time on the site
setInterval(function displayTimeAndDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var hours = today.getHours();
  var minutes = today.getMinutes();
  var seconds = today.getSeconds();

  var date = today.getDate();
  var month = today.getMonth();
  var year = today.getFullYear();

  // Place 0 before the numbers if the are lower than 10
  hours = (hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;

  var amOrPm;

  // Check if it's a.m or p.m
  if (hours < 12) {
    amOrPm = "a.m";
  } else {
    amOrPm = "p.m";
  }

  document.getElementById('currentTime').innerText = month + "/" + date + "/" + year + " " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + amOrPm;
}, 1000);

setInterval(function countdown() {
  // Set the desired date (American date format: Month/Day/Year) to countdown to and the current date
  var endDate = new Date('07/04/2018 09:00 PM');
  var currentDate = new Date();

  // Get the "distance" between the dates
  var distance = endDate - currentDate;

  // Initialize days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var oneSecond = 1000; // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
  var oneMinute = oneSecond * 60;
  var oneHour = oneMinute * 60;
  var oneDay = oneHour * 24;

  // Get distance in days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / oneDay);
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % oneDay) / oneHour);
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % oneHour) / oneMinute);
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % oneMinute) / oneSecond);

  // Place 0 before the numbers if the are lower than 10
  hours = (hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;


  document.getElementById('countdown').innerText = days + " days, " + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes, " + seconds + " seconds"
}, 1000);
```

```html
<head>
  <!--
         New Perspectives on HTML5 and CSS3, 7th Edition
         Tutorial 9
         Review Assignment
   
         Tulsa's Summer Party
         Author: 
         Date:   
   
         Filename: tny_july.html
   
      -->

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Tulsa's Summer Party</title>
  <link href="tny_base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="tny_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="tny_timer.js" defer></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="horizontal">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Night Beat</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tulsa Times</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">City Links</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <img src="tny_banner2.png" id="logoImg" alt="" />
    <h1>Tulsa's<br />Summer Party</h1>
    <h2 id="timeHeading">Welcome to Tulsa</h2>
    <div id="currentTime"></div>
  </header>

  <article>
    <section>
      <h1>Countdown to the Fireworks</h1>
      <div id="countdown"></div>
      <p>Celebrate the nation's birthday at <em>Tulsa's Summer
               Party</em>, a daylong extravaganza in downtown Tulsa on the 4th of July. The festivities start at 9 a.m. with a 5K and 10K walk or race. A great event for the whole family. Sign up as an individual or part of a team.
      </p>
      <p>The <em>Farmer's
               Market</em> is also back with farm-fresh produce, meats, and dairy. There's something for every pallet.
      </p>
    </section>

    <section>
      <p>Live music starts at 11 a.m. and continues through the day with special appearances from <em>Falstaff
               Ergo</em>, <em>Crop Circles</em>, <em>Prairie Wind</em> and
        <em>James Po</em>.
      </p>
      <p>At 9 p.m. enjoy the <em>fireworks</em> that have won awards as the best in the Midwest, designed and presented by
        <em>Wizard Works</em>. Arrive early for the best seats!
      </p>
      <p>After the show, dance the night away to the music of the <em>Chromotones</em>.
      </p>
      <p>See you on the 4th!</p>
    </section>

    <nav class="vertical">
      <h1>Party Links</h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">5K and 10K Run</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Famer's Market</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Wizard Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Falstaff Ergo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Crop Circles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">James Po</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tulsa Fireworks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Prairie Wind</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </article>

  <footer>
    <address>
            Tulsa Summer Party &#183; 
            340 Main Street, Tulsa, OK 74102 &#183;
            (918) 555-3481
         </address>
  </footer>
</body>
```

### Edit:

This time I didn't modify the HTML:

(I put it in a executable code snippet, otherwise I wouldn't be able to format it properly.)

```js
// Function to display current date / time on the site
setInterval(function displayTimeAndDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var hours = today.getHours();
  var minutes = today.getMinutes();
  var seconds = today.getSeconds();

  var date = today.getDate();
  var month = today.getMonth();
  var year = today.getFullYear();

  var amOrPm;

  // Check if it's a.m or p.m
  if (hours < 12) {
    amOrPm = "a.m";
  } else {
    amOrPm = "p.m";
  }

  document.getElementById('date').innerText = date + ":" + month + ":" + year;
  document.getElementById('time').innerText = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + amOrPm;
}, 1000);

setInterval(function countdown() {
  // Set the desired date (American date format: Month/Day/Year) to countdown to and the current date
  var endDate = new Date('07/04/2018 09:00 PM');
  var currentDate = new Date();

  // Get the "distance" between the dates
  var distance = endDate - currentDate;

  // Initialize days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var oneSecond = 1000; // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
  var oneMinute = oneSecond * 60;
  var oneHour = oneMinute * 60;
  var oneDay = oneHour * 24;

  // Get distance in days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / oneDay);
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % oneDay) / oneHour);
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % oneHour) / oneMinute);
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % oneMinute) / oneSecond);

  // Place 0 before the numbers if the are lower than 10
  hours = (hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds;


  document.getElementById('dLeft').innerText = days;
  document.getElmentById('hLeft').innerText = hours;
  document.getElementById('mLeft').innerText = minutes;
  document.getElementById('sLeft').innerText = seconds;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I copied what you put but now my timer just dissapears: http://prntscr.com/ispi93

Comment: @PandaKingBeersy Here on SO (Stacksnippet) it works perfectly, so I guess the result got messed up by CSS respectively the JS messed up the CSS. Can you add your CSS to your question?

Comment: They have been added.

Comment: There is another CSS file but it doesent seem to have anything to do with the timer.

Comment: @PandaKingBeersy Updated.

Comment: Just to clarify, am I copying the HTML and javascript you provided, or is my original HTML supposed to work with the update script? because I just copied the script you updated and the timer still wont display. Im also noticing that if I unlink the CSS, the timer also still wont display.

Comment: @PandaKingBeersy The updated JS is supposed to work with your own original HTML, the first JS I provided is supposed to work with the modified HTML I provided.

Comment: Ive updated the code with what im currently trying to use in my question. The timer displays, but isn't counting (Which was my original issue).

Comment: @PandaKingBeersy Using your updated code in your stacksnippet in your question: remove `setInterval(function() { ... }, 1000); // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second` from your code, it was just an example to show you the syntax of intervals. Also, at the very beginning of your uptaded JS, there's `"use strict";`, delete that too. Then it should work.

Comment: Thank you. Finally figured this out and I am beyond relieved. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @PandaKingBeersy You're welcome! Please don't forget to mark my answer as the one that helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something as simple as this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="minutes"></div>
<div id="seconds"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// set minutes
var mins = 5;

// calculate the seconds (don't change this! unless time progresses at a different speed for you...)
var secs = mins * 60;
function countdown() {
    setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
}
function Decrement() {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        minutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
        seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
        // if less than a minute remaining
        if (seconds < 59) {
            seconds.value = secs;
        } else {
            minutes.innerHTML = getminutes();
            seconds.innerHTML = getseconds();
        }
        secs--;
        setTimeout('Decrement()',1000);
    }
}
function getminutes() {
    // minutes is seconds divided by 60, rounded down
    mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    return mins;
}
function getseconds() {
    // take mins remaining (as seconds) away from total seconds remaining
    return secs-Math.round(mins *60);
}

countdown();
```

Comment: Its for a school assignment and it has to use the JS and the HTML was pre-written. The steps to do it are in my book (Which ive done, which is why i'm confused as to why it isn't workings. He never mentions changing the HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [FlipClock.js](http://flipclockjs.com)

**The html...**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/flipclock.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="your-clock"></div>

        <script src="/assets/js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/js/flipclock/flipclock.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Instantiating in JQuery...**

```
var clock = $('.your-clock').FlipClock({
// ... your options here
});
```

**Instantiating in JavaScript...**

```
var clock = new FlipClock($('.your-clock'), {
// ... your options here
});
```